# What coordinate data could this ASCII file represent?

Tags: shapefile

I have a ASCII file titled coastline.dat.It is read by a FORTRAN file and converted into NETCDF output. A MATLAB file plot displays the coastlines of Europe. There is no documentation whatsoever on what the contents of coastline.dat is as I am inheriting this code from someone else. I am assuming  that the coastline.dat file is the ASCII content of coastlines of Europe originally derived from a binary ESRI shapefile. In order to do something similar for my continent(Asia) is it adequate that I download a ESRI shapefile of Asia and read it in using a programming language of my choice and then write it out in that format ?
Here is a sample of the ASCII file coastlines.dat -

-999. -999.

0.192440  5.669954

-0.114995  5.515063

-0.391921   5.360171

-0.657114   5.195893

-0.887104   5.151303

-1.262597   5.062123

-1.417488   5.008146

-1.560645   4.874377

-1.736658   4.775809

-1.936139   4.686630

-2.198985   4.787544

-2.410200   4.874377

-2.595600   4.930701

-2.771612   4.951822

-999. -999.

-2.771612   4.951822

-2.860792   4.963556

-3.003949   4.975290

-3.301997   5.052736

-3.611779   5.106713

-3.832382   5.184159

-4.238384   5.163037

-4.679589   5.106713

-5.198240   5.041002

-5.341397   5.008146

-5.430576   5.017534

-5.585468   4.984678

-5.848313   4.918966

-6.080650   4.796931

-6.223807   4.754688

-6.444409   4.677242

-6.643890   4.599797

-6.787047   4.543473

-6.873880   4.489496

-7.106217   4.388582

-7.293964   4.278280

-7.491098   4.257159

and so on...

Comment: It looks like a simple list of coordinates with -999,-999 being used to signal to the program when to lift the pen.

Comment: @iant - so the coordinate reference system would be regular lat/lon WGS84 ?

Comment: No information means no information I'm afraid. Until you get a nice picture there's no way to be sure.

Comment: @mdsumner - you want me to upload the MATLAB output?

Comment: "Shapefile" is not synonymous with geodata. There is no reason to believe, from an ASCII file, that a shapefile was a data source. I would suggest you **edit** the title to be closer in line with the question body.

Comment: Assuming this on the African coast it could be WGS84

Comment: Always. Reproducibility is the aspirational standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the extreme apparent age of the data, it seems unlikely that the original data was WGS84.  Just plotting it shows an 0.13 degree shift from even 1:15m coastline (ArcGIS 10.0 Data & Maps "country.sdc\country"):

[image: data plot]

If you do update the coastline data, you'd likely need to identify all other geometry data and update them as well.